# Writing a query with two requirements in overpass turbo - replicating video

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

some of you might have watched this guy Jose Monkey doing an amazing job finding peoples locations. I am trying to learn OSM commands on overpass-turbo through the replication of this video: https://www.tiktok.com/@the_josemonkey/video/7243158161220209962

I've tried following script but no success:

```
/*
This query will find CVS Pharmacies near Wendy's drive-thru locations.
*/

[out:json];

// Search for Wendy's Drive-Thru locations
node["name"="Wendy's Drive-Thru"](around:1000);

// Search for CVS Pharmacy locations within 1000 meters of Wendy's Drive-Thru
node["name"="CVS Pharmacy"](around:1000);

// Output the results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

It seems like, looking for the stores in the area (Winder,GA USA) are not even mapped. Any idea?

Appreciate your help.

Cheers!

Comment: Add the missing POIs to OSM: https://learnosm.org/en/beginner/

Comment: You seem to use wrong tagging, `node["name"="Wendy's Drive-Thru"];out count;` returns 3 hits only. Also `(around:1000)` in the first node statement seems wrong.